# reload is not defined using browsersync with sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, browser-sync

Trying to use sass with browserSync, here's my gulp js.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

var src = {
    scss: 'app/scss/*.scss',
    css:  'app/css',
    html: 'app/*.html'
};

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });

    gulp.watch(src.scss, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(src.html).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(src.scss)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src.css));
        /*.pipe(reload({stream: true}));*/
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

I have to comment out this line `.pipe(reload({stream: true}));` then it will work. I've no clue what's wrong here.

Comment: It's `browserSync.reload({stream: true})`.

Comment: Where is reload defined? Is it a part of gulp, browser-sync, or sass? If not, then you need to import the definition of reload, whatever that may be. ---  @SvenSchoenung seems to be correct (https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I took a pull from this repo https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/blob/master/recipes/gulp.sass/gulpfile.js

Comment: @EuniceChia - I think that repo must be broken.

Comment: Funnily enough it's correct in the accompanying [`readme.md`](https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/blob/master/recipes/gulp.sass/readme.md).

Comment: @SvenSchoenung - You're right! `var reload = browserSync.reload;`